# Workflow Cancels When it Transitions to the Next Stage

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer

I have a 2013 List WF below. All activities are running within an App Step because users only have Read permissions on the List. I know this is crazy but just go with me on this.

[image]

As you can see in the workflow, if the Status is equal to **Under** then it would **Go to Under**.

When the user adds a new item on the list the workflow runs. When I check the status of the WF on the current item it displays:

```
"Retrying last request. Next attempt scheduled in less than one minute. Details of last request: HTTP NotFound"
```

After a few seconds to a minute the workflow cancels and I get the error:

```
"Details: System.ApplicationException:HTTP 404 Item does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user".
```

I take a look at the correlation IDs from the errors and the logs display the same thing that the item does not exist.

I'm lost and need assistance. All the activities in the App Step works fine but when it transitions from one Stage to the next this is when the issue happens.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: where you specified Under Stage ?

Comment: Yes that's correct.